# How to tab second line from grep -A output

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to filter a html file to get only specific values from the file. the file is a html report from metatrader and I would like to filter only the output values table from the html.

This is the sample of html file (report2.html)

```html
<tr align="right">
   <td nowrap colspan="3">Net profit:</td>
   <td nowrap><b>17.74</b></td>
   <td nowrap colspan="3">Balance Drawdown Absolute:</td>
   <td nowrap><b>0.97</b></td>
   <td nowrap colspan="3">Absolute equity drawdown:</td>
   <td nowrap colspan="2"><b>1.39</b></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
   <td nowrap colspan="3">Gross Profit:</td>
   <td nowrap><b>43.91</b></td>
   <td nowrap colspan="3">Balance Drawdown Maximal:</td>
   <td nowrap><b>6.72 (0.07%)</b></td>
   <td nowrap colspan="3">Equity Drawdown Maximal:</td>
   <td nowrap colspan="2"><b>8.02 (0.08%)</b></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
   <td nowrap colspan="3">Gross Loss:</td>
   <td nowrap><b>-26.17</b></td>
   <td nowrap colspan="3">Relative balance drawdown:</td>
   <td nowrap><b>0.07% (6.72)</b></td>
   <td nowrap colspan="3">Relative equity drawdown:</td>
   <td nowrap colspan="2"><b>0.08% (8.02)</b></td>
</tr>
```

If I use

```
grep --no-group-separator -A1 awdown report2.html | sed -n '/^$/!{s/<[^>]*>//g;p;}'
```

I get the folowing.

```
Balance Drawdown Absolute:
0.97
Absolute equity drawdown:
1.39
Balance Drawdown Maximal:
6.72 (0.07%)
Equity Drawdown Maximal:
8.02 (0.08%)
Relative balance drawdown:
0.07% (6.72)
Relative equity drawdown:
0.08% (8.02)
```

The problem is that I need to have the second line just after the first one with tab and I don't know how to make it and also need to have the filename in the first tab.

Output expected is something like this:

```
report2.html    Balance Drawdown Absolute:  0.97
report2.html    Absolute equity drawdown:   1.39
report2.html    Balance Drawdown Maximal:   6.72 (0.07%)
report2.html    Equity Drawdown Maximal:    8.02 (0.08%)
report2.html    Relative balance drawdown:  0.07% (6.72)
report2.html    Relative equity drawdown:   0.08% (8.02)
```

Anyone can help me how to achieve this output?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

`grep --no-group-separator -A1 awdown report2.html | sed -n '/^$/!{s/<[^>]*>//g;p;}' | sed '$!N;s/\n//'`

i have simply added another stream edit command after yours

Comment: Hello. It works, but still don't have the file name as expected output explained. and, could you please explain the sed formula you have used? Thank you

Can I use similar to replace end of line with : by something like you mention? I mean If I have in all end of lines the character : can I apply something to match this character and bring the second line to the end? not sure I'm clear. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative.

```
 grep --no-group-separator -A1 awdown report2.html | sed -n '/^$/!{s/<[^>]*>//g;p;}' | awk 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1'
```